# Is there a good way of setting C/C++ member variables from string representations? (introspection-lite)

Tags: c++, boost, macros, introspection

I've got a struct with some members that I want to be able to get and set from a string.  Given that C++ doesn't have any introspection I figure I need some creative solution with macros, the stringize operator and maybe `boost::bind.` I don't need full serialization or introspection, more an 'introspection-lite'

I'd like to have something along the lines of this:

```
struct MyType {
  int  fieldA;
  int  fieldB;
};
DECLARE_STRING_MAP(MyType,fieldA);
DECLARE_STRING_MAP(MyType,fieldB);

MyType t;
SET_VALUE_FROM_STRING(MyType,t,"fieldA","3")
```

Rather than have a huge `if` statement.

Any idea if there's a neat solution to this?

Related question: [Object Reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1540114/object-reflection)

EDIT: 
Thanks to maxim1000 for the 'map to int Type::*' trick -- this worked for me:

```
#define DEFINE_LOOKUP_MAP(Type) std::map<AnsiString,int Type::*> mapper 
#define ADD_FIELD_MAPPING(Type, Field) mapper[#Field]=&Type::Field 
#define SET_FIELD_FROM_MAP(Type, Field, var, value) var.*(mapper[#Field])=value    

DEFINE_LOOKUP_MAP(MyType); 
ADD_FIELD_MAPPING(MyType, fieldA); 
ADD_FIELD_MAPPING(MyType, fieldB); 

SET_FIELD_FROM_MAP(MyType, fieldA, obj, 3);
```

Comment: I suppose that you would like to write SET_VALUE_FROM_STRING(MyType,t,currentAttr,"3") as well ?

Comment: boost::lexical_cast might be useful too.

Comment: @Matthieu: yes, the 3rd arg could be a string variable, eg so I can parse some text of the form `fieldA=3,fieldB=10` and call into this function

@ltcmelo - yes, `lexical_cast` could be useful for type conversion, but let's assume for the moment that I know that the values are always going to be ints.

Comment: Only ints? Wish I had read that BEFORE writing my generic answer... I thought it could not be since it was so simple :x

Comment: Frankly, mandrill, I think you are trying to solve this in a different language's paradigm. Unless you shift to a C++ way of thinking, you're going to have more or less an impedance mismatch problem.

Comment: I am a C++ coder through and through, I was looking for ways of reducing duplication and massive `if` statements given the power of combining macros and things like boost::bind (which interestingly, no one else has mentioned yet)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If all of them have the same type, you can use something like this:

```
std::map<std::string,int MyType::*> mapper;
mapper["fieldA"]=&MyType::fieldA;
mapper["fieldB"]=&MyType::fieldB;
...
MyType obj;
obj.*(mapper["fieldA"])=3;
```

Comment: This is certainly the sort of syntax I had in mind in terms of binding to `MyType::fieldA` in this way, however I wonder if it's possible to do without requiring the construction of the map

Comment: @the_mandrill: Some explicit mapping has to take place because the variable names are "lost" at compile time.

Comment: @maxim1000: One of the downsides to this solution is the danger of specifying an incorrect member string (ie, not present in the map) and subsequently crashing on null dereference.

Comment: @luke: agree, probably some wrapping class should be implemented around this approach with more acceptable behaviour for incorrect arguments (exception?)

Answer (score 4):

Death to macros.

Some macro-free code i've used in the past for binding names to struc members and converting non-string types to string:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

template<class STRUC>
struct Field
{
    virtual void set (STRUC& struc, const std::string& value) const = 0;
};

template<class STRUC, class FIELDTYPE>
struct FieldImpl : public Field<STRUC>
{
    typedef FIELDTYPE (STRUC::*MemberPtr);

    FieldImpl (MemberPtr memberPtr) {memberPtr_ = memberPtr;}

    virtual void set (STRUC& struc, const std::string& value) const
    {
        std::istringstream iss (value);
        iss >> struc.*memberPtr_;
    }

private:
    MemberPtr memberPtr_;
};

template<class STRUC>
class FieldMap
{
private:
    typedef std::map<std::string, Field<STRUC>*> FieldNameMap;
    FieldNameMap  fieldMap_;

public:
    ~FieldMap ()
    {
        // delete fieldMap_ members.
    }

    void bind (const std::string& name, Field<STRUC>* field)
    {
        fieldMap_[name] = field;
    }

    template<typename FIELDTYPE>
    void bind (const std::string& name, FIELDTYPE (STRUC::* member))
    {
        fieldMap_[name] = new FieldImpl<STRUC, FIELDTYPE> (member);
    }

    void setValue (STRUC& struc, const std::string& name, const std::string& value)
    {
        FieldNameMap::const_iterator iter = fieldMap_.find (name);

        if (iter == fieldMap_.end ())
            throw std::runtime_error (std::string ("No field binding found for ") + name);

        (*iter).second->set (struc, value);
    }
};

struct Test
{
    int id;
    double value;
    std::string tag;
};

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    FieldMap<Test> fieldMap;
    fieldMap.bind ("id", &Test::id);
    fieldMap.bind ("value", &Test::value);
    fieldMap.bind ("tag", &Test::tag);

    Test test;

    fieldMap.setValue (test, "id", "11");
    fieldMap.setValue (test, "value", "1234.5678");
    fieldMap.setValue (test, "tag", "hello");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I can think of two solutions.

**Use macros to create a structure definition and its map from the same source**

By using macros and reworking your structure definition, you can use the technique as described in this excellent answer without separately declaring the map.

Rewrite your structure definition like this, and put it in a header by itself:

```
BEGIN_STRUCT(MyType)
FIELD(int, fieldA);
FIELD(int, fieldB);
END_STRUCT
```

Then #include it twice.  Before #including it the first time:

```
#define BEGIN_STRUCT(x) struct x {
#define FIELD(x, y) x y;
#define END_STRUCT };
```

Before #including it the second time:

```
#define BEGIN_STRUCT(x) namespace x ## Mapping { typedef x MappedType;
#define FIELD mapper[#x]=&MappedType::x;
#define END_STRUCT }
```

I've not tested this, so a few details may be off.

If macros are banned in your environment, you could instead create the structure definition and its map from whatever external tool you wish (Perl, Python's [Cog](http://nedbatchelder.com/code/cog/), etc.).

**Use a reflection library for C++**

Although C++ doesn't directly implement reflection or introspection, add-on libraries are available.  I've used [ROOT's Reflex](http://root.cern.ch/drupal/content/reflex) library with good results.

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't willing to change the struct to something else, you really don't have a choice - you're going to need the big if statement to tell which field you're dealing with. You can hide it (and make it easier to write) with macros, but it's the same structure, and you're going to have to just deal with it.

Here's an example of how you might write that macro - it does make usage simpler, but it's still not 'short' by any means.

```
//Assumption: at the time you want to use this, you've got two strings, one with the 
// name of the field to set (key), one with the value to set (value). I also assume

typedef struct MyType {
  int  fieldA;
  int  fieldB;
} MyType;

// fldnamedef - name of the field in the structure definition (const char *)
// convfunc - name of a function that takes a value, returns a fldtypedef
// s - structure to put data into
// key - const char * pointing to input field name
// value - const char * pointing to input field value
#define IF_FIELD_SET(fldnamedef, convfunc, s,  key, value) {\
  if (strcmp(#fldnamedef, key) == 0) {\
    s.fldnamedef = convfunc(value);\
  }\
}


int main()
{
  MyType t={0,0};

  IF_FIELD_SET(fieldA, atoi, t, "fieldA", "2");

  printf("%d,%d\n",t.fieldA, t.fieldB);
}
```

And here's the pre-processor output that the IF_FIELD_SET line turns into:

```
{ if (strcmp("fieldA", "fieldA") == 0) { t.fieldA = atoi("2"); }};
```

Comment: I think you missed something: "fldnamedef" makes this useless, it's just a much longer way of writing `t.fieldA = atoi("2");`... There is no introspection there.

Comment: C++ doesn't DO introspection in the way the OP really needs. The OP's choices are wrap the if's in macros or switch data structures. This answer is one way to wrap the ifs in macros to make it slightly easier to work with.

Answer (score 1):

Introspection emulation ? That sounds like a challenge, that's for sure.

The interface does not really please me, so I would propose an alternative:

```
struct MyType
{
  int fieldA;
  int fieldB;

  void setField(std::string const& field, std::string const& value);
};
```

Now the challenge is for `setField` to select the right field, and indeed a map seems appropriate. However we need to encapsulate the type information somewhere (unless you plan on using only ints, in which case... there is no difficulty), so a map of functors is in order.

```
static std::map<std::string, Functor<MyType>*> M_Map;

// where Functor is

template <class Type>
struct Functor
{
  virtual void set(Type& t, std::string const& value) const = 0;
};

// And a specialization would be
struct SetfieldA : public Functor<MyType>
{
  virtual void set(MyType& t, std::string const& value) const
  {
    std::istringstream stream(value);
    stream >> t.fieldA;
    // some error handling could be welcome there :)
  }
};
```

Note the use of `std::istringstream`, now you can support any type as long as they correctly interact with an `std::istream`. Thus you can support user defined classes.

And of course, the part here is all about automation!

And automation like in macros.

```
#define INTROSPECTED(MyType_)                                                    \
  private:                                                                       \
    typedef Functor<MyType_> intro_functor;                                      \
    typedef std::map<std::string, intro_functor const*> intro_map;               \
    static intro_map& IntroMap() { static intro_map M_; return M_; }             \
  public:                                                                        \
    static void IntroRegister(std::string const& field, intro_functor const* f){ \
      IntroMap()[field] = f; }                                                   \
    void setField(std::string const& field, std::string const& value) {          \
      intro_map::const_iterator it = IntroMap().find(field);                     \
      if (it != IntroMap().end()) it->second->set(*this, value); }

#define INTROSPECT_FIELD(Class_, Name_)                                          \
  struct Set##Name_: public Functor<Class_> {                                    \
    virtual void set(Class_& t, std::string const& value) {                      \
      std::istringstream stream(value); stream >> t.Name_; } } Setter##Name_;    \
  Class_::IntroRegister(#Name_, Setter##Name_)
```

Usage like this:

```
// myType.h
struct MyType
{
  INTROSPECTED(MyType);

  int fieldA;
  int fieldB;
};

// myType.cpp
INTROSPECT_FIELD(MyType, fieldA);
INTROSPECT_FIELD(MyType, fieldB);

// Any file
MyType t;
t.set("fieldA", "3");
```

Of course the usual caveat apply: off the top of my head, never compiled it, may kill kittens and worse.

Answer (score 0):

This is more or less what the "<<" operator is for. Sadly, the language doesn't provide a default version for structs and classes like it does for the assignment operator, but you can make your own easily enough.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to change away from a structure to another data type, then you have some different options.

If the fields are all of the same type, just use an STL map:

typedef std::map MyType;

```
MyType t;

t["fieldA"] = atoi("3");
printf("%d\n", t["fieldA"]);
```

If they are of different types, then you could go with converting the values when you take them out of the structure:

```
typedef std::map<std::string, std::string> MyType;

MyType t;
t["fieldA"] = "3";

printf("%d\n", atoi(t["fieldA"]));
```

You can wrap the get and the conversion in field-specific macros, to make it a little easier to write.

```
typedef std::map<std::string, std::string> MyType;
#define fieldA(v) atoi(v["fieldA"])

MyType t;
t["fieldA"] = "3";

printf("%d\n", fieldA(v));
```

That does have the disadvantage of not looking much like a structure element access.

You might try making MyType a class and use individual functions for each field. This at least allows you to get different types per field, but you'll still have to have the big block of ifs to do a set. Of course, since you can put that into the object, it'll be easier to use. Of course, you've turned structure field access into object method calls. Still, it's pretty easy to use, and that might buy you something.

```
class MyType {
public:
  set(std::string key, std::string value) {
    if (key == "fieldA") m_fieldA = atoi(value.c_str());
    if (key == "fieldB") m_fieldB = atoi(value.c_str());
  };

  int fieldA() { return m_fieldA; };
  int fieldB() { return m_fieldB; };
private:
  int m_fieldA;
  int m_fieldB;
};

MyType t;
t.set("fieldA", "3");
printf("%d\n", t.fieldA());
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason that a dictionary/map wouldn't work? You could hash the strings to make lookup faster.